# how to find record with the same list of relations

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Hello I have a model `Conversation` with field `users` that is in relation `@ManyToOne`

Now I want to ask db if there is any record that contains same list as the one given to search. I don't care about the order of elements in list i just want to check is there a record that has list or relations with records 1,4,5 where 1,4,5 are id`s of users. How can I do that ?